# How to easily print ascii art in c (alternative for R"EOF()EOF"))

Tags: c, ascii-art

I like including ASCII art in my projects and until now I used to print it like this:

```
 printf (R "EOF(


    *               MMM8&&&            *
                  MMMM88&&&&&    .
                 MMMM88&&&&&&&
     *           MMM88&&&&&&&&
                 MMM88&&&&&&&&
                  MMM88&&&&&&
                    MMM8&&&      *
          |\___/|
         =) ^Y^ (=            .              '
          \  ^  /
           )=*=(       *
          /     \
          |     |
         /| | | |\
         \| | |_|/\
  _/\_//_// ___/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_/\_
  |  |  |  | \_) |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  

)EOF");
```

is there an alternative as easy to use as this for C?

Comment: The best you can get is to add quotes at the start and end of each line. The C compiler is going to automatically stitch these lines together to form a single C string.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/161868-how-use-ascii-art-c-cplusplus.html#post1196999) helps: _Another option would be to create the ASCII art in a text file, thereby preserving the "image" source visually, and simply read/print this text file._

Answer (score 4):

Just use literal strings. Of course, you'll need to encode some characters (notably quotes, double quotes, backslashes, newlines, etc...).

```
puts(
"    *               MMM8&&&            *\n"
"                  MMMM88&&&&&    .\n"
"                 MMMM88&&&&&&&\n"
```

and so on. Remember that [puts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) is appending a final newline (you don't want to use [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), because some characters, notably  `%`, have a special role, and because it is probably slower). If you don't want that final newline, consider also [fputs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs).

In C and C++, two (or more) string literals are assembled in one.

BTW, you could also generate such C code, or perhaps have something which transforms any file (e.g. your ASCII art) into an initialization like

```
const char data[] = { 0x20,
```

etc...